# If this Page Show This Else Show This

Tags: php, if-statement

On all pages apart from the contact page, I want it to show the following in the inc-header.php include.

```
<p><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></p>
```

On the page `contact.php`, I want it to show:

```
<p><a href="index.php">Home</a></p>
```

This should be possible correct?

Comment: why not to include a common menu contains all the links into each file? having just "home" link is a way outdated last century practice.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
<?php
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'contact.php')){
     echo '<p><a href="index.php">Home</a></p>';
}
else{
     echo '<p><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></p>';
}
```

Comment: +1, but the OP doesn't mention if the page is a file called `contact.php`. Maybe based on URL is better?

Comment: Thank you for all the feed back, the one above did the job.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

```
if ($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == '/contact.php') {
    echo '<p><a href="index.php">Home</a></p>';
} else {
    echo '<p><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></p>';
}
```

Comment: On my server, this would need to be compared to '/contact.php', as it including a leading slash. Not sure if this is server specific or not.

Answer (score 4):

There is a global variable named [`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) that contains the name of your page currently requested. Combined with [`basename()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) this should work:

```
if( basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php') == 'contact' ) {
    // Contact page
} else {
    // Some other page
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the quick and dirty solution is:

```
<?php
$current_page = 'contact';
include('inc_header.php');
....
?>
```

In inc_header.php:

```
<?php
if($current_page == 'contact') {
    // show home link
} else {
    // show contact link
}
?>
```

Comment: And where do you set the value of `$current_page` ?

Comment: in contact.php! (assuming contact.php is the file where the contact page is loaded and the inc_header.php include statement is placed)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple if statement, but this will only work for your contact page.  You could also use a simple function in your inc-header file that would work like so:

```
function LinkToPageOrHome( $script, $title ){
   if ( strtolower( $_SERVER[ 'SCRIPT_NAME' ] ) == strtolower( $script) ){
       $script = 'home.php';
       $title = 'Home';
   }
   echo '<p><a href="' . $script. '">' . htmlentities( $title ) . '</a></p>';
}
```

It's sort of a blunt approach from a design standpoint, but you could use `LinkToPageOrHome( 'page.php', 'My Page' );` in multiple templates and never worry about having a page link to itself.