# set php variable to find current page

Tags: php

```
$pages = array('Text1.php', 'Text2.php', 'Text3.php');

// $currentpage depends the page you're on

$currentId = array_search($currentpage, $pages);
```

I have php script which is accessed through an `include(Text4.php)` and the `include(Text4.php)` is stored in all the three php scripts above in the array.
 Now what I want to do is set up the `£currentpage` so that it should equal the page the user is currently on and match a value in `$pages` which should be the filename of the current page.

My question is that in the code above, how should $currentId variable be written to perform the functionality it is suppose to acheive?

Comment: last sentence : your `$currentpage` variable, you mean, don't you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997016/if-this-page-show-this-else-show-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File name only:

```
$currentPage = basename(__FILE__);
```

__

Directory name + filename:

```
$currentPage = __FILE__;
```

__

Directory only:

```
$currentPage = __DIR__;
```

Comment: The page `Text4.php` is in the same folder as the other php pages in the array. So is it better fir me to use file name only or use directory and filename?

Comment: Ok last question is the variable set as simply as you have defined them? Im just surprised a simple line of code like that will be able to determine the user's current page. I thought it would be more complex haha

Comment: Thanks David for your answer. Yeah suprised that is all is needed

Answer (score 0):

//if you want a path

```
$currentpage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

//if you only want the actual file name (literally "Test.php")

```
$posofslash = strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'/');
$currentpage = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],$posofslash);
```

Comment: Don't bother using PHP_SELF, it's exploitable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a piece of code I use for my browser game. The wording has been changed slightly but the code itself works excellent. Any php code can be put inside the 'if' statements, where I used 'print.'

```
    ///---Various Navigation & Functions Depending on Current Page---///

$findpage = strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'/');  
$currentpage = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],$findpage);
if ($currentpage == '/home.php'){
 print "This message is displayed when the client is on the 'home' page.";
 print "If you so chose, you can put the entire 'home' page code in here.";
 print "While keeping this the only code being executed.";}
if ($currentpage == '/features.php'){
 print "This message is displayed when the client is on the 'features' page.";
 print "If you so chose, you can put the entire 'features' page code in here.";
 print "While keeping this the only code being executed.";}
if ($currentpage == '/menu.php'){
 print "This message is displayed when the client is on the 'menu' page.";
 print "If you so chose, you can put the entire 'menu' page code in here.";
 print "While keeping this the only code being executed.";}
if ($currentpage == '/store.php'){
 print "This message is displayed when the client is on the 'store' page.";
 print "If you so choose, you can put the entire 'store' page code in here.";
 print "While keeping this the only code being executed.";}
```